# Cordova camera plugin to create half screen for camera and other half for selection menu

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am a trying to implement Instagram like camera interface(half screen is camera and other haalf is selection menu) using cordova camera plugin. Can anybody help me with this? Couldn't find a good source

Comment: Yep.There is no plugin which gives that kind for feature. have you tried using HTML5's canvas tag and .getUserMedia ?. There maybe chances that it wont work in old devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement an hybrid view, 
[check this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en).

I did it to implement a, JAVA SurfaceView (implementing the camera inside it) over a CordovaWebView.

To give you some direction:

In the JavaScript for your plugin have something like:

```
SurfaceViewAdd:function(){
    cordova.exec(
        function(){//success function},function(){//error function},'MYPlugin',action,JSON[])
},
```

Once the plugin is installed in your cordova project, you can call this JavaScript function which will call the JAVA native code.

On the JAVA side, MainActivity:

```
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity
{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

        MYPlugin.setCwv(this.appView);
);

....plus all function you might need (to release the camera onPause event for example)..

}
```

The class of you plugin:

```
public class MYPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {


    public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
///Manage the input of your plugin from Javascript
//call functions inside your plugin class to implement a SurfaceView on top of the CordovaWebView
//Send back a successful callback to your JavaScript once the webview is implemented
        }

... ///all you need to implement the surfaceView and the cameraView inside the surfaceView ...

        public static void setCwv(CordovaWebView cwvInput) {
        cwv = cwvInput;
        }
}
```

And you'll need a plugin XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="com.you.myplugin"
    version="1.0.0">
    <name>MyPlugin</name>
    <description> ... </description>
    <license> ... </license>
    <author> ... </author>

    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
    </engines>

    <js-module src="www/js/my_plugin.js" name="MyPlugin">
        <clobbers target="MyPlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="widget">
            <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
            <feature name="MyPlugin" >
                <param name="android-package" value="com.you.myplugin.MyPlugin"/>
                <param name="onload" value="true"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/you/myplugin" />

    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Take the time to read the article and good luck.

Comment: Thanks mate :) Will try this.Thanx again