# Cordova Custom Camera Plugin

Tags: cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

Hello friends we have a project developed in cordova framework with image capture functionality.
Right now we are using default camera plugin , but the requirement is need to have custom camera with auto detect document(Check) and auto capture it.
Any pointers.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My advise would be to start from there: [Tutorial to understand hybridview.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en)

Once you're fine with those concepts:
Build a custom cordova plugin that does the following: Implement a `SurfaceView` (or its equivalent in iOS), on top of your `CordovaWebView`. In the `SurfaceView`, implement the management of your Camera and thru the caption of your `Camera.PreviewCallback()` implement the Library you need for picture recognition and get the result back to JavaScript.

[In addition have a look at that answer that I had already given in the past.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646225/cordova-camera-plugin-to-create-half-screen-for-camera-and-other-half-for-select/37654806#37654806)

Good luck.